# Leak with Drywall and Wood Framing

Tags: water, drywall, concrete, leak, toilet

I've got, potentially, a silly question.

We're having some work done in our basement, including the addition of a bathroom. The guys working here were working on the main to install the up-flush system when one of the workers forgot and used the toilet and sink pouring all of that waste all over the other guy working, down the drywall and wood framing and onto the concrete floor. They left that afternoon and when I looked I saw it was all soaked. They came back next day and bleached the concrete with mop and bucket, but I'm a little uneasy about the waste that was absorbed into the drywall and wood.

Am I overreacting or could this pose a health concern and have them address it?

Comment: Since it was only a "splash" not soaking in inches of waste I would think a wipe down would be ok, if the sheetrock was not mudded it would be easy to replace and you could request that but the wood is fine and won't be affected. Many bathrooms have backups and usually a good cleaning is enough.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't going to cause mold or permanent issues to the drywall or wood.  That means there are basically two issues - aesthetics and cleanliness.  From a cleanliness aspect bleaching and normal cleaning is pretty par.  Crap can be hard to get out of lumber though.  If you have exposed wood framing and it has crap on it and it will remain exposed, they should replace it if you can see even the faintest trace.  Simply if you can see it, then it exists.  Meaning if there are brown marks, you can still touch crap particles.

From an aesthetics point of view everything should look exactly like it did before or better.  So the advice I am giving is set the expectations for them.  I don't care if they need to repaint, so be it.  They messed up (literally) and now have to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. Luckily (I believe) it was just urine and water from the faucet. They didn't do anything before they left that day and came with a mop and bleach for the concerete the next day. I'm just concerned about the drywall that was soaked down and the wood framing that was drenched.

Comment: Is the paper on the drywall wrinkled?